# How to send email using data of a row whose particular column is just edited in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

I want to automate my work of sending email.
For this i created google apps script, but it is not working.

my goal is : if i update column I of any row to "Yes" than email must be send to email id of that row only by adding their username and password. and if possible email status will also change to "email sent on date"

This is my table
[image: table]

Code:-

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = e.Range;
  if(range.getColumn()== 9 && e.getValue()=="Yes")
  {
    var celladdress = 'E'+ e.getRowIndex();
    var emailid= ss.getRange(celladdress).getValue();
    var sub = ' - ';
    var uname = ss.getRange('G'+ e.getRowIndex()).getValue();
    var pass = ss.getRange('H'+ e.getRowIndex()).getValue();
    var b = "Your details are as follows: \n Username :" +uname+ "\n Password : "+pass+ "\nThis is for your information please. \nThanks and Regards";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailid, sub, b);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: (Upper/lower)Case is important. Have you looked into official documentation for "event objects"? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for documentation. Also, see [mcve]: Provide a clear problem/quote errors and show off your research effort.

Comment: e is not a range. So getValue() is not a method of e. e gets loaded with event object try looking at it with Logger.log

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You had a few mistakes in your script like using `e.getValue()` instad of `range.getValue()`, I have corrected these mistakes.

Moreover and most importantly, to be able to send emails using triggers you need to use installable triggers as simple ones do have restrictions as the `MailApp` service requires authorization. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) you can find more information about this.

To create an installable trigger ( if you have not already do so ), go to your script editor and then to **Edit->Current Project Triggers** and the trigger pannel **Add Trigger**. Select your function (onEdit) and set the **event type** to **on edit**.

This is your piece of code with the typos corrected:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getColumn()== 9 && range.getValue()=="Yes")
  {
    
    var celladdress = 'E'+ range.getRow(); 
    var emailid= ss.getRange(celladdress).getValue();
    
    var sub = 'Credentials-reg';
    var uname = ss.getRange('G'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
    var pass = ss.getRange('H'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
    var b = "Your details are as follows: \n Username :" +uname+ "\n Password : "+pass+ "\nThis is for your information please. \nThanks and Regards";

    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailid, sub, b);
  }
  
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)